# Expected number of trials before k successes where multiple successes can occur at each trial

Tags: probability, distributions

Let's say there are $N$ balls, $l$ of them have unique colours, $N-l$ of them are black.

$D$ people uniformly randomly sample $n$ balls without replacement. Each person's sampling is independent of the others'. So they take $n$ balls, make copies of them, and then put the originals back for the next person.

Now I want to find at least $k$ of the $l$ uniquely coloured balls. I'm going to ask each person one at a time (in random order) for all of their non-black balls. What's the expected number of people I have to ask before I have collected at least $k$ uniquely coloured balls?

If I only ask one person then the probability that I collect at least $k$ comes from a binomial distribution ($X \sim B(l, \frac{n}{N})$). I imagine this as asking "what is the probability that the person sampled at least $k$ of the $l$ balls".

Where I come unstuck is that if I now ask a second person, the probability that I find more coloured balls is dependent on how many, and which, coloured balls I found the first time.

I wrote out the possibilities for small numbers by hand and it looks like $(zp)^k$ (where $p$ is the probability that a particular coloured ball was sampled) gives the probability that $k$ balls have been found after asking $z$ people.

I got that 'result' by asking, "what's the probability that between 2 people I find 2 different balls". If I use $p_{ij}$ as the probability that person $i$ gave me ball $j$ then the answer is:

$P(\textrm{2 balls between 2 people}) = p_{11}p_{12}+p_{11}p_{22}+p_{21}p_{12}+p_{21}p_{22} = 4p^2$

My reasoning is that the four terms are the four possible ways that I could get 2 balls from 2 people, each way is independent so I can add them up.

I did this for a couple of different numbers and saw the $(zp)^k$ result.

I'm not sure that my reasoning is sound or that my result is even useful in answering the original question. I've been staring at this for an afternoon now and I don't think I'm getting much further.

So, what should I do?